# How to use scripting inside another terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have `PJSIP` configured on target device (ARM Toradex). I am using it to make calls using SIP. Whenever I need to start it, I use below command:

```
./pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

and then its own terminal starts where we can enter commands to use it. I am planning to make a script which will automatically starts the PJSIP when the target device boots. So I included this in script but the problem is whenever the command is executed its own terminal starts and it doesnt accept another command which I have written in script.

For example:

```
echo "Starting PJSIP..."
./pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

So after this, its own command line terminal starts like in below image:

[image]

where `>>>` is the point where we have to enter its command to start making calls. Now lets say `m` is the command which initiates `make call`. Now how to include `m` in scripting so that after `PJSIP` starts, command `m` is executed to make a new call .?

One way which I think of doing this is recording all the response of the command in a variable and then checking if it contains `>>>`. If yes, this means we are now in PJSIP terminal. Is this way of doing it correct.?

Comment: Complicated at first, I believe 'expect' will get you what you need.

Comment: @bc2946088 Yeah its complicated but I have found an alternative way only for this PJSIP. I have made a config file and while starting the pjsip I point it to the config file and inside that file, I have put all those command I needed to run inside its terminal. But generally speaking, I guess this is not the actual solution for this kind of situations. Well thanks for `expect`, I will definitely look for it and will reply back with it